# No acceptable answers what can I do about my bounty + I have worked out a solution

Tags: discussion, bounty

My question [filtering kendo ui scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37971364/filtering-kendo-ui-scheduler) was posted/updated with addition information requested but no solution. I had one user offer help for which I added a general up-vote as a thank you for their time and effort and an up-vote on a comment that they made. Eventually I decided to place a bounty of 150 reps.

In the 7 days that the bounty was running I had no more updates or request for information from anyone. I on the other hand have found a solution (and willing to share if anyone is interested ). As it stands the other poster will get the bounty even though they did not provide a solution and they gained their 2 up-votes from me.

Is there anything that can be done in these circumstances?

Comment: Well, write your answer and accept it. The bounty points won't be given back to you though.

Comment: You have your answer, that is the most important I think and now it is upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks.... yes in the grand scale of things the fact I have a solution is much much more important...I just thought in such circumstances allowance can be made based on the actual 'help' received which was none from the moment the bounty was started all the comments/solution given were given before I started the bounty looking for a more definitive answer. I feel I've given away hard earned reputation but not received anything back

Comment: Note that the other answer is simply bad and should not have gained +3 votes... "try this" with zero explanation is not good quality SO answer.

Comment: Placing a bounty has a cost. Doing so means you've accepted that cost, whether you've gotten additional help as a result or not. The help explains that bounties are non-refundable.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no actual answer to your question - post your own answer and accept it.

Bounty will be lost (as one can't receive their own bounty), but it is by-design price for attention to your post.

Comment: Thanks Alexei... This is what I have done. I was contemplating starting the bounty @50 but then thought it is such a complex issue no one would bother so decided to give 150. Still I'm glad I fixed it myself as I now have a far better understanding of the intricacies of the Kendo scheduler. As for the bounty being 'the by-design price for attention' in my case I got nothing... no more activity (comments or answers) from the time the bounty started until it ended - apart from my own posted answer.